# Where do I export function in my npm package so developers can import them?

Tags: javascript, npm

I am trying to create an npm package for others to use. Currently, my project looks like this:

```
lib/
  forms/
    Button.js
    ...
  layouts/
    Row.js
    ...
node_modules/
src/
  forms/
    Button.tsx
    ...
  layouts/
    Row.tsx
    ...
package.json
...
```

`package.json` specifies that only lib/**/* should be published. An `npm` script compiles my `*.tsx` files into the `*.js` files in the `lib/` directory.

Ideally, after someone installs my package, they would be able to import Button like this:

```
import {Button} from "@whiterook6/components/forms"
```

But the way the import works currently is if it looks like this:

```
import {Button} from "@whiterook6/components/lib/forms/Button"
```

How and where do I put my index.js files, and what content goes inside them, so that they

- reference the lib/**/*.js files properly, instead of referencing src/ files, since those won't be published;
- allow other devs to only include the bits they want (so the total compiled project size remains small); and
- have a "nice" import statement?

Also, what is the correct export syntax I should use?